# use user defaults to save array when one item is deleted

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, tags, nsuserdefaults

I want my swift code to use user defaults to save the array arr. When the user hits the delete button on the tableview cell it removes that cell and the label. What I also want to do in func handle register is remove the number from array arr so if cell displaying cell 2 is deleted I want 2 delete from array arr. When the app closes it should save only the numbers that were not deleted. Just like the picture below represents a before and [image: after.]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  var arr = [0,1,2,3,4]
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customtv
       cell.lbl.text = "\(arr[indexPath.row])"
       cell.deleteBTN.tag = indexPath.row
       cell.deleteBTN.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
       return cell
    }
    @objc func handleRegister(_ sender: UIButton){
         arr.remove(at:sender.tag)
         tableView.deleteRows(at:[IndexPath(row:sender.tag,section:0)],with:.none)
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(arr, forKey: "arrNum")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 118 }

    var tableView = UITableView()
    var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setTableVIew()
    }


    func setTableVIew(){
    
          
         
       
        
        let VCframe = view.frame
        let height = VCframe.height * 0.8
           
        let widthx = VCframe.width

   
             tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: widthx - 20, height: height)
          
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
  
      
        tableView.register(customtv.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
 




    
}
class customtv: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var backView : UIView = {
      let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width  , height: 110))
      view.backgroundColor = .green
      print(self.frame.width)
          return view
      }()
      

      
      override func layoutSubviews() {
         backView.clipsToBounds = true
         backView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110)
   

      }
    lazy var lbl : UILabel = {
        let press = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 3, width: 120 , height: 50))
        press.backgroundColor = .yellow
        press.text = String("1")
            
        return press
    }()

   
 


 
    lazy var deleteBTN : UIButton = {
        let press = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 3, width: 65 , height: 50))
        press.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        press.setTitle("DELETE", for: .normal)

        return press
    }()

 
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
    addSubview(backView)
    backView.addSubview(deleteBTN)
    backView.addSubview(lbl)
}
```

}

Comment: I see you are using `UserDefaults` already to persist your `arr` whenever you remove an item. So what is the issue with your current code?

Comment: @CongNguyen when the user deletes a row and then quits the app and then reopens the app. The item from the array is not delete. So the user defualts is not having any effect on the array.

Comment: How do you load your persisted data from UserDefault?